# Where will i put my image resources?

Tags: android, eclipse

I tried making images folder but I cannot call it by using R.images.(filename) also, putting the images in raw folder does not solve the problem.
is there any way where I can use the images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is well explained in the [Drawable Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html) section of the documentation.

You'll end up with `drawable-xxxhdpi` and other folders. Put your `my_image.png` in those folders at the proper DPI levels and you'll be able to access those images with R.drawable.my_image.

If you need an easy image resizer library I have one over at https://github.com/jlindenbaum/res-resizer